# Google Bar Chart with Laravel and SQL Query

Tags: php, laravel, google-visualization

I am trying to make and display a Bar Chart using Google Charts on my Laravel dashboard,
the query I am trying to use is Supposed to join two tables and fetch the columns to get the average according to which department the training was done under.

This is the query I am using:

```
SELECT AVG(training_hours.Hours) as AverageTraining, training_hours.dept_id, departments.department_name
FROM training_hours INNER JOIN employees ON training_hours.employee_id = employees.id
INNER JOIN departments ON training_hours.dept_id = departments.id
WHERE training_hours.dept_id = employees.dept_id
GROUP BY departments.department_name;
```

When i try to convert into Laravel eloquent I am getting something like this ->

```
$barChart=DB::table('training_hours')
        ->Join('employees','employees.id','=','training_hours.employee_id')
        ->Join('departments','departments.id','=','training_hours.dept_id')
        ->where('training_hours.dept_id','`employees.dept_id`')
        ->select(DB::raw('AVG(training_hours.Hours) AS AverageTraining'),'training_hours.dept_id','departments.department_name')
        ->groupBy('departments.department_name')
        ->get();
```

Now how do I display this in the bar chart on my dashboard?

I already have another chart being displayed, which is a Pie Chart the codes for that are like this:
Controller

```
$userId = Auth::id();
        $users = User::paginate(10);
        $hoursDone=DB::table('training_hours')
        ->where('employee_id',$userId)
        ->select(DB::raw('SUM(Hours) AS TrainingHoursDone'))
        ->get();
        
        $hoursLeft=DB::table('employees')
        ->where('id',$userId)
        ->join('training_hours', 'employees.id', '=', 'training_hours.employee_id')
        ->selectRaw('TrainingHoursRequired - sum(Hours) as HoursLeft')
        ->get();

        $chartData="";
        foreach($hoursLeft as $hLeft){
            $chartData.="['".$hLeft->HoursLeft."',     ".$hLeft->HoursLeft."],";
        }
        foreach($hoursDone as $hDone){
            $chartData.="['".$hDone->TrainingHoursDone."',     ".$hDone->TrainingHoursDone."],";
        }
        $arr['chartData']=rtrim($chartData,",");
        return view('admin.dashboard.index', compact('users', 'chartData'));
```

Dashboard.blade

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['corechart']
    });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Training Hours Done', 'Training Hours Left'],
            <?php echo $chartData; ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Hours Completed Vs Hours Remaining',
            legend: 'none',
            pieHole: 0.4,
            tooltip: { trigger: 'none' },
            slices: {
                0: {color: 'orange'},
                1: {color: 'blue'}
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

How can I do the bar chart? Please do help me with this.

Comment: Can you show us the result of your code?

Comment: @mepasososo my results come out as `array=[]` whenever I do `dd($barChart);`. It does not fetch and display any data